# error C2143 and error C2059 missing ";" before "{"

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, multidimensional-array

I can not compile it. I dont know what is going on, it seems good for me. The error which I get:

```
error C2059: syntax error "{"
error C2143: syntax error: missing ";" before "}"
error C2143: syntax error: missing ";" before "}"
```

X.h

```
   class X
    {
        friend symbol;
    public:
        X();
    private:
        int tab[4][3];
    };
```

X.cpp

```
X::X()
{
    tab[4][3]={{0,1,0},{1,0,1},{2,-1,0},{3,0,-1}};
}
```

Where's a problem?

Comment: What version of VC++ are you using? VC++6, VS2005 C++, VS2010 C++ .. etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do can basically be done with a C++11 compliant C++ compiler. Unfortunately you are using Visual C++ (Not sure which version) but this kind of thing won't work yet with any official release of VC++. Had VC++ been *fully* C++11 compliant this would have worked:

```
private:
    int tab[4][3] {{0,1,0},{1,0,1},{2,-1,0},{3,0,-1}};
};
```

It just so happens the code below does work with C++11 compliant compiler, but it also works for VC++ starting from VS2013. Something that may suit you better is using `std::array`:

```
#include <array>

class X {
  friend symbol;
  public:
    X();
  private:
    // Create int array with 4 columns and 3 rows.
    std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 4> tab;
};


X::X()
{
    // Now initialize each row
    tab[0] = { {0, 1, 0} };   // These assignments will not work on Visual studio C++
    tab[1] = { {1, 0, 1} };   //     earlier than VS2013
    tab[2] = { {2, -1, 0} };  // Note the outter { } is used to denote
    tab[3] = { {3, 0, -1} };  //     class initialization (std::arrays is a class)

    /* This should also work with VS2013 C++ */
    tab = { { { 0, 1, 0 }, 
              { 1, 0, 1 }, 
              { 2, -1, 0 }, 
              { 3, 0, -1 } } };
}
```

I generally use `vector` in place of arrays like `int tab[4][3];` This can be treated as vector of vectors.

```
#include <vector>

class X {
  friend symbol;
  public:
    X();
  private:
    std::vector < std::vector < int >>tab;
};


X::X()
{
    // Resize the vectors so it is fixed at 4x3. Vectors by default can
    // have varying lengths.
    tab.resize(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        tab[i].resize(3);

    // Now initialize each row (vector)
    tab[0] = { {0, 1, 0} };
    tab[1] = { {1, 0, 1} };
    tab[2] = { {2, -1, 0} };
    tab[3] = { {3, 0, -1} };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `tab[4][3]={{0,1,0},{1,0,1},{2,-1,0},{3,0,-1}};` has several problems.

1. `tab[4][3]` attempts to refer to one element of `tab`, not the whole array.
2. It indexes out of bounds--with `tab` defined as `tab[4][3]`, legal indices run from `tab[0][0]` through `tab[3][2]`.
3. You're trying to assign an array, which (even if you fix the preceding) isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax, if C++11 is available for you

```
X() : tab {{0,1,0},{1,0,1},{2,-1,0},{3,0,-1}} {}
```

Comment: Visual C++ 2013 (official release) is yet to be fully C++11 compliant and this fails. Previous versions of VS C++ are less compliant